# Changing the font of a ul in Bootstrap and CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I tried to change the font of my ul with CSS but it doesn't work. I tried the code below.

```
ul {
   font-family: Arial;
}

<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> My Account</a></li>
       </ul>
```

Comment: Bootstrap specifies a font set in its css. To use the Bootstrap class names but have your own font over-ride it i'd put "!important at the end of your font declartion. Like so....."font-family:Arial !important;" or if you feel comfortable editing the source Bootstrap go in there and change the font for the classes you are using

Comment: Doesn't work :/ I'll try editing the source code.

Comment: You're placing the text inside your `glyphicon` tag (which isn't closed), place it after your closed `span` tag and it will work. And use `navbar-right `instead of `pull-right` [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is caused by your `<span>` tag not being closed. The following works for me:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It worked. But could you explain to me why that was the problem? I'm trying to learn Bootstrap and not just memorize stuff :P

Comment: Since ```<span>``` was not closed, the ```glyphicon glyphicon-user``` styles were likely being applied to everything passed that point, which includes the 'My Account' text.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for explaining!